# Xcode: Button defaulting to centre of view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uistoryboard, uicontrol

Strange thing happened just now. I set my VC size to 4.7 inch in the storyboard settings and then tried to add a standard button control to the top left of my view controller. It wouldn't let me place it where I wanted, and defaulted to centre position in view controller. Same happened when I tested another UI control. Any idea why this is happening? 
Edit: I also can't select any controls from VC in storyboard to move their position. So the button is in centre position but I can't select it from there to reposition.

[image]

Comment: As long as you don't give us more information, screenshot of your `UIStoryboard` it will be very hard to help you with your problem.

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: Do you have any constraints applied to the button or view?

Comment: No constraints applied yet at all, brand new project. I'm using auto layout. The view controller is utterly standard, the one that comes with creating a new single application. I didn't do anything to the project except to set it to 4.7 inch size before trying to add the button to top left corner.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? And what version of iOS are you building for?

Comment: Using version 6.4. No particular version of iOS in mind - 7 or 8 I guess. It is literally just a single view controller and I'm trying to drag in a button. I haven't had this issue before with this version but as I said it is first time I changed size to 4.7 inch iphone.

Comment: Ok, I still have no idea what caused this but I've started a new project and the issue is gone. Absolutely bizarre!